# Is the 'no specific reference' close reason for reals?

Tags: discussion, scope

Consider [this migration](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6049/is-the-best-pronunciation-of-yhwh-yahweh). If this is an acceptable question we need to get rid of that close reason.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* kind of a weird reason because we allow questions about the hermeneutical process proper; but in this case it's appropriate. That question is more about the Hebrew language than about the meaning of the Bible. I don't think it belongs here and have voted accordingly.